# What happens in memory if multiple instances of a class are retrieved with the same variable name in C#

Tags: c#

I have an instance of a class named person 1. What happens in memory if I get an instance with the same name again? can i use the first generated address when i create the object for the second time. Is a new address assigned in memory?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {
      Person person1 = new Person(); 
   }
```

Stack:
person1 - 0x234567 memory adress

Heap:
Person - 0x234567

Comment: Variable "names" have really nothing to do with this issue and almost don't exist in compiled code. You are creating and discarding multiple objects. The discarded object will likely be GC'd at some point but not likely immediately, suggesting that new objects will occupy new address locations.

Comment: You're working with a language that abstracts memory away to the point that often you can pretend that memory is infinite. As such, you really shouldn't be *worrying* about how the memory is manged for you.

Comment: thanks for the answers.
stay healthy

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case: the variable *isn't used*, so the compiler actually interprets this as a discard - it removes `person1` entirely, just [doing a `pop`](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwDNoACACmwDsMTsSBeEgBgG5aSAeElN7Aaj4BKALAAoAN5iSJAAowoAZwiUSAB3lLKARgYlKMAO6yNysoLZiAvmIACAJmOLlJcZaA) on the result of the `newobj`, as though you'd done `_ = new Person();`. The objects created will be eligible for garbage collection at some indeterminate time.

In the more general case: it all depends on scopes, captures, etc; if the same "local" ends up being reused (which isn't absolutely guaranteed), then only the last value assigned will still be reachable, so: if nothing else roots the created objects, then  once again: they will be eligible for garbage collection at some indeterminate time.

Comment: thanks for the answer.
stay healthy